# Public Key Auth not working in CyberDuck

Tags: ssh, cyberduck

I'm trying to connect to a server via ssh with public key.

When I try ssh command from the terminal everything works fine:

```
ssh user@server.org
```

but when I try to connect from cyberduck I get "connection refused"

Those are my values:

```
server: user@server.org
user:
use public key authentication: ˜/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Follow this instructions : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hd4oL3WIPVM

Comment: This question is off-topic and should be moved to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Mac, you might have a standard password saved in your login keychain that doesn't match the public key password. If you previously connected with standard `password` authentication, and later switched to `publickey`, there might be a mismatch as both are saved using the same name in the keychain.

Use Mac OSX [Keychain Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_Access) to remove (or edit) the entry for `server.org`.

I see that you have an empty username in your CyberDuck settings, and used the server field with the user@server.org format. To simplify SSH/SFTP connection settings, you can use [`~/.ssh/config` to consolidate (SFTP) settings for `server.org`](http://trac.cyberduck.ch/wiki/help/en/howto/sftp) for both the terminal `ssh` and CyberDuck. CyberDuck will pick up the settings if you edit the server name `server.org` in either "Open connection" or "Add/edit bookmark". *Tested using the latest/current [snapshot build of CyberDuck](http://trac.cyberduck.ch/wiki/help/en/faq#SnapshotandBetabuilds), as there have been problems in older versions - there are other bugs with bookmarks in the current snapshot though.*